# how to create liferay Table in mySql?

Tags: mysql, liferay

how to see my liferay table in mysql database?
i have created portal-ext.properties in liferay home.but i cant see my liferey table mySql..
table is created in docroot/web-inf/sql in eclipse IDE... 
help me where i m wrong and which thing missing?

```
#
# MySQL 
#
include-and-override=portal-ext.properties
include-and-override=${liferay.home}/portal-ext.properties

jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/kportal?useUnicode=true&characterEn
coding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=root
jdbc.default.password=ubuntu123
schema.run.enabled=true
schema.run.minimal=true
```

Comment: Are you looking for a plugin's table? Or for Liferay's tables? In case you are creating your own plugin: Do you use servicebuilder?

Comment: @OlafKock i know the service builder. but when i created service.xml file and create table(eg.abc) in it. my table(abc) is not showing in mysql . should i have to create table manually? or using service.xml file will create table in mysql.. pls tell me how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables created through service-builder will only be created once you *deploy* your plugin to the actual server (and run the server), *not on build* time. Also, your plugin needs to deploy correctly - if initialization fails (e.g. due to missing pieces or dependencies that are not met), the tables will not be created.

Also, the tables by default will be named with the namespace you gave as a prefix. So if you declare a namespace X (in service.xml) and an entity named Y, the table to look for will be named X_Y.

Also, remember you'll have to run `ant build-services` after you edited your service.xml. Then deploy it and wait for a log message similar "...your plugin... is available for use" to be sure it deployed correctly. (Edit: This is no longer printed for portlets, only for the other plugin types, so you might not see it when you deployed your plugin)

If this doesn't help, please give more information. Currently you don't give any details about what you've actually tried. You'll find more steps and details on the [development guide](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/service-build-5).

Also, make sure

- that the account you use for the database has CREATE TABLE permissions (you use root in your configuration above - that should do the trick)
- that you're checking the correct database in case you have multiple
- that Liferay actually picks up your configuration file. The startup log will tell you which portal-ext.properties files are read, as well as which database it will use. In case you can't find the name/location of your portal-ext.properties file, make sure that you indeed have a file with this name. A common problem on windows is that people create portal-ext.properties.txt (and Windows hides the .txt part of the name)

Comment: hello tell me how many step i have to follow for small portlet with mysql connection?
i have done following things.
preferences->liferay->installed plugins SDK
preferences->server->runtimeEnvironments
any thing missing in my eclipse?

Comment: hello.. as u say run "ant build-services" ,i run this from .right click on project->liferay->buildservices. is this correct?

Comment: i cant create table in mysql from service.xml pls help me

Comment: i cant get this msg..."your plugin... is ready for use" any thing is missing?

Comment: Sorry, I've been mixing it up. The message originally is "... available for use" but it's no longer logged for portlets, only for hooks, themes and layout templates. So you won't see it. But you'll have to deploy the plugin and have the appropriate permissions on the database level to create tables. Note that you're mentioning "kportal" in your code above - make sure that you check the correct database in case you have several. And check the startup logs - you should find some information there which database is actually used.

Comment: if i create service.xml file , then should create table manually in mySql? or it will automatically create in mySql?

Comment: i use mysql query browser, when in build service my table show in "service.xml-diagram mode" but  i cant find in mySql query browser. i can find my table in web-inf/sql/table.sql .... may i in correct way?

Comment: Did you ever deploy your plugin? The tables should be created upon deploy. The CREATE TABLE statements will also be in the WEB-INF/sql directory, yes, but that's more or less the documentation what needs to be done. As long as you don't deploy to the server (which has a database connection) there's no way the IDE can know what database you want to deploy to. If this doesn't help, please start over and write down *all* steps that you do and what you expect&experience - it's really hard to give recommendations when you state "I can't see it" over and over without knowing what you actually do

Comment: hello i m write all my work.
1)install liferay-eclipse,set runtime server,set plugin SDK,set ant home,
2)start server,ant build,
3)put portal-ext.properties in classes folder,create service.xml file in web-inf,from overview mode in service.xml file i build servce, i got the msg "build successfully",after this i can show my table in web-inf/sql folder.. 
still any thing remaining ???

Comment: i have do above thing, i have one java file and two jsp files edit.jsp and view.jsp, edit.jsp file contain text fields, when i enter data in edit.jsp it should be show in view.jsp and that data  store in database also.thatswhy i want connection with database.
give me logic how can i do this things. pls help me. i realy need help...

Comment: this is my portal-ext.properties... i put it into to liferay/tomcat/webapps/root/web-inf/classes
 #
 # MySQL 
 #
 jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
 jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEn
 coding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
 jdbc.default.username=root
 jdbc.default.password=ubuntu123
 schema.run.enabled=true
 schema.run.minimal=true